# Find explicitely an element of SL$_2(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, computational-mathematics, computational-geometry, unimodular-matrices

Let $\Gamma=\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ act on $\mathbb H=\{z \in \mathbb C: Im(z) > 0\}$ by $\gamma z=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, where $\gamma$ is the matrix $\left[\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix}\right]$.

It is well known that a fundamental domain for this action is $D=\{z \in \mathbb H: |Re(z)|<\frac12, |z|>1\}$.

I want to write a program for which I need to display the unique representative in $D$ of the orbit of various points of $\mathbb H$.

To this end, I think I have write a procedure that finds, given any $z_0$ in $\mathbb H$, the (unique up to sign) element of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ that sends $z_0$ into $D$. How does one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An existing proof of the precise statement contains some constructive ideas.

First we find $c$ and $d$ such that $|cz_0+d|^2$ is minimal. We must have $\gcd(c,d)=1$ automatically, so we pick $a'$ and $b'$ such that $a'd-b'c=1$. It remains to take an integer $n$ closest to the real part of $\frac{a'z_0+b'}{cz_0+d}$ and put $a=a'-nc,b=b'-nd$ to build a final $\gamma$. To ensure it is unique, you have to deal not only with choice of sign, but also with $\gamma z_0$ landing in the boundary of $D$ (and it will still not be unique in some degenerate cases you should be aware of).

Comment: Thank you. I did not mention the case when $\gamma z_0$ lands in the boundary for simplicity and because... well, it happens with zero probability :)

Comment: What other degenerate cases are you alluding to  by the way?

Comment: I mean points with nontrivial stabilizers ($i$, $\exp(\pi i/3)$ and $\exp(2\pi i/3)$). But it happens with zero-squared probability ;)

Comment: ...and they land in the boundary so this is included in the first degenerate case, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, of course.